# What module should I use for pagination in NodeJs and Express JS for Mysql backend?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, pagination

I am new to NodeJs and Express Js.

And I am looking for pagination module that will be useful for ajax as well as listing records of Mysql Database.

Comment: In my opinion if you are looking paginator, it means that you are looking for an ORM. You would like to work with prepared collections for that kind of aproach (paginator). I would rather suggest you to use knex.js as a query builder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try **express-paginate** at https://github.com/expressjs/express-paginate. 
 For SQL use see https://github.com/expressjs/express-paginate/issues/12. 
 It also has view locals/middleware added for your views, so you can easily add "Next" and "Previous" links.

Comment: He positively asks for Mysql Database pagination, you suggest him mongoose-paginate...

Answer (score 1):

You may use node-pagination or express-pagination.

Please check list of module:
https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/pagination